# Javascript Unzip/Decrypt Zip File Apache Cordova

Tags: javascript, unzip, password-protection, zip, apache-cordova

I have a password protected zip file on my local storage (android phone) and want to open/read it.
I can't open the protected zip file with the File Reader API. 
JSzip or cordova-plugin-zip doesn't support passwords as far as I know (There is no parameter for the password string)

1.) Have you any suggestion how I can encrypt the zip file?

2.) What if there is an option to do that, but the password string is in the javascript code. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this plugin to Encrypt/Decrypt files https://github.com/disusered/cordova-safe

You can send set Encrypt/Decrypt from JS

Comment: Thats for that but it didn't actualy work. It does something with the file but then the zip file is corrupt.